# How to display the current time in .phtml with caching enabled?

Tags: magento2.2, cache, custom-block, block-cache

I created a really simple block in my child theme:

/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_time_block" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom-time-block.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom-time-block.phtml:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                 <?php
                 $now = new DateTime();
                 echo $now->format('H:i:s');
                 ?>
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

So when I clear the cache, the time that is displayed, is the time when I cleared the cache. The time is not the current time. So how can I get this working **without**:

- cacheable="false" (because this block is going to be dislayed everywhere, so each page will not be cached)
- Javascript: I want to display the server time, not the client time

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why not AJAX it will give you updated time without cache

Comment: Thank you for your comment @kunj. That might be a solution. Is there an existing API endpoint I can use to GET the current time?

Comment: API? you can try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196432/magento-2-send-form-data-to-controller-using-ajax-and-return-result-to-phtml

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Javascript with MomentJs. I echo the date into a hidden input like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="system-time" value="<?php echo $now->format(DATE_ISO8601); ?>" />
```

Yes, this is still cached, but it doesn't matter because I can parse the string with MomentJS to get the correct TimeZone like this:

```
 var systemTime = moment().utcOffset($('#system-time').val());
```

or

```
 var systemTime = moment().parseZone($('#system-time').val());
```

I found information about this here: http://www.herveguetin.com/formatting-date-times-and-displaying-them-nicely-with-moment-js/. That article explains how to display date and time in Magento 2 with MomentJS.