# Magento2 - How to send mail of form data using AJAX in custom form?

Tags: magento2, ajax, forms

I have created one inquiry form in magento 2. now I want send data to given EmailID using ajax.
here is my code

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Full Name">Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="company name">Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyname">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email id">Email Id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailid">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact number">Contact Number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactnumber">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="product name">Product Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">

  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</form>
```

now what is the code to add ajax so I can send email of form data

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196432/magento-2-send-form-data-to-controller-using-ajax-and-return-result-to-phtml

Comment: Check above link it will help you

Comment: has it been fixed now ? if yes then please share your answer, if not share your finding.