# Magento 2.1.7 - Unable to send form data to controller using AJAX

Tags: magento2, controllers, forms, jquery

I am trying to fetch input value but I am unable to get values in the controller.
Here is my code,

> Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Crud\Crudatfrontend\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();       
    }
}
```

> Controller\Result\Result.php

```
<?php

namespace Crud\Crudatfrontend\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
    {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($this->getRequest('height')->getParams());exit;
        $height = $this->getRequest()->getParam('height');

        if (isset($height)) { 

        echo $height; exit();

        } 
        else{
            echo "not found";
        }



        $weight = $this->getRequest()->getParam('weight');
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Crud_Crudatfrontend::result.phtml')
                ->setData('height',$height)
                ->setData('weight',$weight)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

> view\frontend\layout\crud_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block\Index" name="crud_index_index" template="Crud_Crudatfrontend::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

> view\frontend\layout\crud_result_result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block\Index" name="crud_result_result" template="Crud_Crudatfrontend::result.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

> view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

```
<div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <form name="form_height" method="POST" id="form_height">
                       height <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control input-md">
                       weight <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control input-md">
                        <input type="submit" id="calculateTotalSubmit"  name="calculate-total-submit" value="Calculate Total">
                    </div> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


    <script>
    require(['jquery'],function(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {


            jQuery("#form_height").submit(function(){

                var heightValue = jQuery("input[name='height']").val();
                var weightValue = jQuery("input[name='weight']").val();

                var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'crud/result/result/' ?>";
                jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {height:heightValue,weight:weightValue},

                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response.output);
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
                       });
            return false;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

> view\frontend\templates\result.phtml

```
<?php 

    echo $block->getHeightData();
    echo $block->getWeightData();

?>
```

> Block/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Crud\Crudatfrontend\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        )
    {           
         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   


    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

    public function getHeightData()
    {
        return $this->getHeight();
    }

    public function getWeightData()
    {
        return $this->getWeight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add form key

```
<form name="form_height" method="POST" id="form_height">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
       height <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control input-md">
       weight <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control input-md">
        <input type="submit" id="calculateTotalSubmit"  name="calculate-total-submit" value="Calculate Total">
    </div> 
</form>
```

Secondly, use serialize to get all the data in your from when calling ajax

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {


        jQuery("#form_height").submit(function(){

            var heightValue = jQuery("input[name='height']").val();
            var weightValue = jQuery("input[name='weight']").val();

            var url = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'crud/result/result/' ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),

            success: function(response){
                console.log(response.output);
                window.location.href = url;
            }
                   });
        return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: I have added echo "not found" in the controller, still getting the same msg like before

Comment: use `echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
die;` in your controller and check if you are getting post variable

Comment: Before changes, I was getting values in the console, now I am getting undefined in the console

Comment: print_r($_POST); this is printing array()